# Kernel compilation error

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I was trying to compile the Linux kernel.

I am getting the following error:-

"No rule to make target `arch/x86/kernel/entry_32.o', needed by`arch/x86/kernel/built-in.o'."

Before this I configured the kernel(didn't do anything extra except the default options).
configured the kernel using "make gconfig". The config was generated. I am using x86 32 bit machine (Fedora 9) kernel version 2.6.30.

Finally I used :- 
    "make bzImage"
to compile.

Tried to search the net for a solution but without success.
How to fix these errors??
Kindly help.

Thanks,

Sourabh

Comment: maybe better to ask a question in superuser.com

Comment: Double-Posted on SuperUser (with the comment that it would more fit on StackOverflow XD)

http://superuser.com/questions/54732/linux-kernel-compilation-error

Comment: I think this falls squarely into "programming related."  Appropriate for SO.

Comment: I didn't know people compiled new kernels for Fedora 9 - I assumed they always went with the pre-built kernels supplied with the OS!

Comment: This is more than appropriate for SO.

Comment: @ kieveli : people don't compile new kernels for Fedora 9 but some people can compile new kernels "on" Fedora 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call make before make bzImage.

make clean or make mrproper would perhaps help too depending how much you screwed up already.

Comment: Was just going to post steps starting with mrproper. Yes, he should make mrproper, make xconfig (or) menuconfig, save the current kernel config then just type 'make'.

Comment: I already tried both make clean and make mrproper.
Still the error doesn't go away....

Comment: Delete the directory, and extract the source again, following the instructions this time more carefully. :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the previous answer, you should take a look at how to compile a kernel, the fedora way ([here](http://www.howtoforge.com/kernel_compilation_fedora)). Not sure this is still up-to-date, but leveraging the provided tools is a good idea sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you didn't actually configure the kernel. Did you use any of "make config", "make menuconfig", "make xconfig"?

Are you running an x86 distribution or an x86_64 one? In the latter case, you need the x86 32 bits compilation environment too.

Advice : this is a poorly asked question. You didn't give any relevant information : Linux distribution and architecture, kernel version you want to compile, the commands you tried and the messages you got.

Comment: I configured the kernel using make gconfig.
The config was generated.
I am using x86 32 bit machine (Fedora 9) kernel version 2.6.30.

Finally I used make bzImage to compile.